# ReSharper does not recognize custom qunit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, resharper, qunit, resharper-7.0

I want to use ReSharper to run my javascript unit tests. But I don't get ReSharper to detect my custom test functions.

```
customTest("my test", function() {
  // do some stuff to test my code
  ok("The test run successfully");
}

function customTest(testName, testFunc) {
  // do some stuff to initialize the test object
  // this is supposed to happen for every test
  test(testName, testFunc);
}
```

When running this file all tests are executed, but the tests aren't added to the ReSharper testrunner. Any ideas?

Comment: Should it help anyone, don't forget to check the [JetBrains page on unit testing](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/ReSharper_by_Language__JavaScript__Unit_Testing.html) with info on how to include QUnit tests. (Specifically, it mentions to include the proper QUnit js/css files.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think resharper can recognize your tests. I just runs your function calls but how would it know what your tests are?